# Como eu posso criar conexões vpn usando serviços de cloud como o AWS?

Tags: vpn

Queria usar o serviço do Google Cloud ou o AWS pra me conectar à internet via VPN, tendo assim uma rota alternativa para a conexão, pois meu provedor tem um ping alto em relação a determinados sites, e baixo em relação aos servidores dessas empresas, e acho que este processo pode resolver. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na AWS você precisa configurar, primeiramente, um VPG (Virtual Private Gateway). Ele vai permitir que posteriormente os túneis de VPN sejam criados. Depois crie um Customer Gateway, que é na verdade somente SEU IP Público que você vai utilizar para fechar a VPN com a AWS. Com o VPG e o Customer Gateway a VPN (do lado da AWS) pode ser configurada. O processo é simple, basta iniciar o wizard de para criar uma nova VPN e Vincular o VPG, Customer gateway, que foi definido anteiormente, e por final você deve definir para qual rede privada seu VPN irá se comunicar (essa é a rede que você usa na AWS). Após a AWS provisionar sua VPN ela vai te fornecer um arquivo de configuração com os dados da conexão IPSec que foi criada, você deve selecionar a configuração mais adequada ao seu equipamento (do seu lado). Esse arquivo contem todos os dados para fechar a conexão VPN IPSec (pre-shared key, ikei, peer).  Após fechar a VPN não se esqueça de configurar o roteamento nas suas Route Tables para que o tráfego seja roteado entre a sua rede da AWS e sua rede local.

Nesse link tem esse procedimento que descrivi em detalhes: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/SetUpVPNConnections.html

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante, só n dou upvote pq eu não posso ainda kkk. Acho que sua excelente explicação facilitou bastante a compreensão do processo.